# WSO2 API Manager - custom workflow don't work because carbon don't find the new class

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm working on WSO2 am and I'm trying to implement a custom workflow.
I read all the documentation and many blog on it but nothing solve my pb.

I add my jar with just my new class on */repository/components/lib*

After, I comment

```
<!--SubscriptionCreation executor="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.SubscriptionCreationSimpleWorkflowExecutor"/-->
```

in ***/_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/workflow-extensions.xml***

Finally, I add  this line

```
<SubscriptionCreation executor="org.wso2.sample.workflow.Printer"/>
```

to the same file.

But when I try to add an application or to subscribe or anything using workflow, WSO2 crash because he don't find my class.

Someone can help me ?
Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I find the problem :

WSO2 am run with java 7 and my eclipse build my jar with java 8 so both don't work.

The solution is to build jar with java 7

Comment: if it solves your problem, accept it as answer. otherwise this will show in unanswered question list

Comment: I can't for the moment. Stack overflow say that i can do it after tomorrow